# Suppose that $X$ is a set of ordinals. Then $\bigcup X$ is transitive

Tags: proof-verification, ordinals

> Suppose that $X$ is a set of ordinals. Then $\bigcup X$ is transitive.

---

Please help me verify my attempt! Many thanks for you!

---

**My attempt:**

Suppose that $\alpha\in\beta\in\bigcup X$. Then $\alpha\in\beta\in\gamma$ for some $\gamma\in X$. It follows that $\alpha\in\gamma$ since $\gamma$ is an ordinal and thus transitive. Thus $\alpha\in\bigcup X$. Hence $\bigcup X$ is transitive.

Comment: That is correct, but you might want to split $\alpha\in\beta\in\dots$ into two statements to make it clearer what exactly you are concluding from what.

Comment: Thank you for your response @user10354138 ^^

Comment: @Isabella The setup $\alpha\in\beta\in\cup X$ is correct in this context. There is no profit in starting with $\alpha,\beta\in\cup X$.

Comment: It's ok @Isabella. I'm sure that you have learned something from that comment.